# Convert string to dictionary - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following data:

```js
d0 = "{\"a\":\"324jk324\",\"b\":\"42793bi42\",\"c\":\"894h42hi\"}"

d = JSON.parse(d0) \\ produce the data below

// {"a":"324jk324","b":"42793bi42","c":"894h42hi"}
```

I was trying to get the data type and log it as string:

```js
console.log(typeof d) // string
```

I want to convert the string to a dictionary so that I can reference data as follows:

```js
d['a'] \\ 324jk324
```

How can I do this?

Comment: No such thing as a dictionary in JavaScript.

Comment: Your `d0` value should have surrounding quotes.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl sorry I forgot to add it in the question. it does have it

Comment: If you do have surrounding quotes, then your code looks fine except for the incorrect usage of line-terminating comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your `d0` variable should have surrounding quotes and your comments should be forward-facing i.e. `//`.

```js
const d0 = "{\"a\":\"324jk324\",\"b\":\"42793bi42\",\"c\":\"894h42hi\"}";

const d = JSON.parse(d0); // produce the data below

console.log(d['a']); // 324jk324
```

If you are having trouble with basic syntax, you should probably re-learn the how to define variables.

I suggest you visit:

- https://javascript.info/variables
- https://javascript.info/string
- https://javascript.info/comments